# Remove row of numpy array based on values from two columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with four columns and many rows:

```
>>> dat
array([['4/5/2004', '17', 0.0, 0.0],
   ['4/5/2004', '7', 0.0, 0.0],
   ['4/5/2004', '19:48:20', 58.432488, -135.9202205],
   ['4/5/2004', '19:48:32', 58.432524300000004, 0.0],
   ['4/5/2004', '19:48:36', 58.4325365, -150.9202813]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to remove all rows where the value in columns 3 or 4 equal 0 so the result would be:

```
   ([['4/5/2004', '19:48:20', 58.432488, -135.9202205],
   ['4/5/2004', '19:48:36', 58.4325365, -150.9202813]])
```

I can do this one column at a time with:

```
a = dat[~(dat[:,2]==0), :]
```

Which returns rows where value in column 3 does not equal 0. I could do this iteratively for multiple columns, but it would be convenient to do it all in one command.

I thought something like the following two examples would work (but they do not):

```
a = dat[~(dat[:,2]==0), :] or dat[~(dat[:,3]==0), :] 
a = dat[~(dat[:,2&3]==0), :]
```

Hopefully there's some simple syntax I'm missing and can't find in the numpy help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data array is `2D`, we could slice and look for the valid ones -

```
dat[~(dat[:,2:4]==0).any(1)]
```

Alternatively, we can use `np.all` on the `!=0` ones -

```
dat[(dat[:,2:4]!=0).all(1)]
```

---

When the columns of interest are not contiguous ones, we need to slice them using those column IDs and use the same technique. So, let's say the column IDs to be examined are stored in an array or list named `colID`, then we would have the approaches modified, like so -

```
dat[~(dat[:,colID]==0).any(1)]
dat[(dat[:,colID]!=0).all(1)]
```

Thus, for the stated case of columns 3 and 4, we would have : `colID = [2,3]`.

Comment: You can do `2:4` -> `2:`.

Comment: Heh I like your way of doing logical and/or reduce.

Comment: All the answers yielded exactly what I wanted. I chose this since the command seemed the most concise.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Coming from MATLAB background, that comes first to my mind :)

Comment: Makes sense. I come from MATLAB too, but numpy has been my bread and butter for a while now, so reduce jumps out first.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `&`:

```
>>> dat[(dat[:,2] != 0) & (dat[:,3] != 0), :]
array([['4/5/2004', '19:48:20', 58.432488, -135.9202205],
       ['4/5/2004', '19:48:36', 58.4325365, -150.9202813]], dtype=object)
```

which yields the element-wise "and".

I've changed it for `!= 0` thus the `&` which avoids the additional inversions with `~`.

Answer (score 2):

You got the idea of using `or` conceptually correct. The main difference is that you want to do logical or (`|`) or logical and (`&`) (just like you are using logical not (`~`)).

This works because an operation like `dat[:,3] == 0` creates an array or booleans of the same size as a column of `dat`. When this array is used as an index, `numpy` interprets it as a mask. Splitting off the mask array to highlight this concept:

```
mask = (dat[:, 2] != 0) & (dat[:, 3] != 0)
dat = dat[mask, :]
```

Another way to compute the mask would be as follows:

```
mask = np.logical_and.reduce(dat[:, 2:] != 0, axis=1)
```

`np.logical_and.reduce` shrinks the input array across the columns (`axis=1`) by applying `np.logical_and` (which is the function that processes the `&` operator) to the rows, so you get a True where all the elements of the selected portion of each row are True.